# Consider a C variant, where comparison operators return all bits set for true values and 0 for false

Tags: c, programming-languages

I'm looking at a question and can't seem to see how it would deviate from normal C. In C, 1 represents true (of course any non-zero value is also considered true) and 0 represents false. In what scenarios would a C variant deviate from traditional C, if we instead returned all bits set when conditions evaluate to true. To me it seems the same, but I know there must be an aspect im not considering, or just not thinking of the question in the right way. Would really appreciate a hint in the right direction.

Comment: No variants of C will do that. `true` is defined to be `1`, and none of the acceptable implementation have all-ones to represent `1`.

Comment: Things like `foo = array[a > b];` (indexing a two-element array from a conditional) would become invalid. I'm pretty sure you'd break a lot of code that assigns directly or indirectly `int`s from the result of conditional expressions.

Comment: The value of an "all bits set" `int` would be implementation dependent.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: A variant is not a conforming implementation. A variant is something that varies from the standard. The question asks the reader to consider a language different from standard C.

Comment: OK, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Hako: It is doubtful you have shown the full question. The sentence “Consider a C variant, where comparison operators return all bits set for true values and 0 for false” merely tells the reader to do something in their mind (“consider”). It does not ask them to describe the consequences, explain any value gained or lost, or do anything else tangible. To pose a sensible question on Stack Overflow, show the complete question or assignment.

Comment: Any code that is relying on the numerical value of `true` will break. Is that something you are considering?

Comment: The question furthermore asks what the advantages and disadvantages would be. I thought if I could think of a case where they deviate (my question), then I could think of some advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I can't think of any advantages. But a disadvantage would be that on platforms with different data type width and/or signed numbers representation the value for `true` will be different. Not speaking of deviating from the common convention of binary logic.

Comment: Are you looking to unify logical and bitwise operations?

Comment: I remember from the distant past that BASIC used all ones for `true` and there were no separate instructions for boolean evaluation.

Comment: Why would the standard constrain the compiler in such a way?  I'd have to find the specific language, but won't it apply to assignments?  I mean given `int x = a > b;` then `x == 1 || x == 0`, but that doesn't necessarily mean that if (a > b) requires an evaluation process that yields 0 or 1 for purposes of taking a branch?  Now I have to go read the standard again...  I hate getting old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An advantage is that nominally branchless selections can be written more easily:

```
// Select c or d based on comparison of a and b.
static int Select(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int mask = a < b;
    return c & mask | d & ~mask;
}
```

In standard C, this can be written as `return a < b ? c : d;`, but that nominally involves testing `a < b` and then executing a branch instruction. Branch instructions often have deleterious effects on processor performance, and we seek to avoid them in high-performance code. So have a bit mask instead that can be used to make the selection using on logical instructions, not branches, could be beneficial in some circumstances.

However, questions like this are hypothetical and dated. A compiler might optimize `a < b ? c : d`. Or, even if using a mask is better, there is a question of how the compiler is going to generate it to implement `a < b`—that might in itself involve performing a test and executing a branch instruction, thus negating the benefit. So questions like this generally do not have good answers in isolation. They serve only in a classroom context to prompt or portray student familiarity with the material.

Comment: note that you get the same behavior in standard C with `unsigned mask = -(a < b);`

Answer (score 1):

The reason "non-zero" is considered **true** is probably tied to the underlying CPU architecture. Most assembly languages implement conditional control flow by comparison opcodes (on x86 the `cmp` instruction is used, or other instructions will implicitly set the zero flag) that set the corresponding 'zero flag'. Then conditional branching instructions will test the zero flag and jump to a new location only if it is set.

The zero flag is set only if the value is zero, so it avoids an additional comparison instruction to check if a value is exactly equal to one.

For example, on x86 machines this:

```
int fn(int x)
{
    if(x) return 1;
    else  return 0;
}
```

would become (something like) this:

```
fn:
    cmp    edi, 0
    jz    .L2

    mov    eax, 1
    ret
.L2:
    mov    eax, 0
    ret
```

Assuming your question is "why does C treat non-zero values as true?" (which I wasn't completely sure about), then the reason is because it's the most efficient way to use the instruction sets that we have on modern hardware (that being said, the example above is unnecessary and inefficient, but just to show the point).